# Deixando uma table hidden usando javascript, primefaces e JSF

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsf, primefaces

Eu tenho uma tela que pede o cnjp, dtini e dtfim, status e um botão consultar. No javascript, a função consulta chama uma outra função que valida os campos. Caso os campos estejam ok, uma table com os dados acima mencionado fica visible. 
Porém, o botão de consultar é um submit, assim sendo, ele atualiza a página, voltando para seu estado inicial que é a table hidden. 
Há alguma forma de eu fazer essa regra usando o meu Bean com algum componente do primefaces onde eu possa fazer um if?

```
function Consultar() {
            if (Valida()) {
                with (document.frmConsSolicAltDomicBanc) {
                    var hdnAcaoBotao = document
                            .getElementById("frmConsSolicAltDomicBanc:hdnAcaoBotao");
                    hdnAcaoBotao.value = "C";
                    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
                    action = "#{ConssolicaltdomicBancBean.lista()}";
                    submit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Acima a minha função que verifica se os dados estão ok. 
Estou aberto a novas ideias de como implementar essa regra.

Comment: com Javascript vc consegue colocar um `preventDefault()` no click do botão assim.. vc consegue executar um ação antes de fazer o submit do form!

Comment: Já tentou colocando um `event.preventDefault();` logo ali antes da sua var?

Comment: Eu pensei em colocar um event.preventDefault(); mas estou parado em como chamar o submit novamente. Poderias me passar um exemplo?